# How to move from one scene to another by time. Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How to switch from one scene (viewcontroller) to another by time (like slideshow).

with no buttons, automatically:

**scene1** > *wait 5 sec* > **scene2** > *wait 5 sec* > **scene1**

and so on.

Comment: Check out [`NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). It'll do exactly what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a programmer, could you please give me a code?

Answer (score -1):

In viewDidLoad of every Scene, add following -

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(slideToNext:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
```

add following function to each viewcomtroller .m -

```
    -(void)slideToNext:(NSTimer*)timer {
        //perform your segue or pushViewController
        [self.timer invalidate];
      }
```

Comment: not works... Property 'timer' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'; did you mean to access instance variable 'timer'?

Comment: You have to create a property in you class -                               @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;

Comment: Sorry...: Invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression (string: - (void)slideToNext:(NSTimer*)slide {)

Comment: To be more correct: Error: -[ViewController slideToNext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Debug it. This sia different problem. This has to do something with your signature of slideToNext.